# Pandas - Calculate Mean and Variance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For a current project, I would like to calculate both the mean and variance for a group of values.

My existing code calculates the mean through `.agg('mean')`. I tried to add `, 'var'` inside the bracket, which however yielded an error:

*f"numpy operations are not valid with "
pandas.errors.UnsupportedFunctionCall: numpy operations are not valid with groupby. Use .groupby(...).mean() instead*

Is there any smart tweak to make the code below work?

```
newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter'])['rating_recommend', 'rating_outlook'].agg('mean')
```

Comment: May be I"m missing something. you just need to var in the parenthesis, see answer below. I might very well have misunderstood the question. so please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 'var' for variance in the parenthesis.

```
newdf = (df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter'])['rating_recommend', 'rating_outlook']
         .agg('mean', 'var'))
```